# I want selected textfiles to act as binary files when merging

Tags: git-merge

For reason I want to be able to merge a text file without risking a merge. Is it possible to treat a text file as a binary file in this case? It is important that no one do this merging by misstake

Answer (score 0):

Using [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), you should be able to mark a file as binary:

```
path/to/my/file binary
```

But that would prevent even to see a diff, considering [`binary` is a pre-defined macro](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_macro_attributes).
So use instead:

```
path/to/my/file -merge -text
```

That will work only for branches done *after* adding that `.gitattributes` file.